# Why do the conversion specifiers, %o and %x, work differently for printf() and scanf() in C?

Tags: c, io

I am learning C from the book "C Primer Plus" by Stephen Prata. In chapter 4, the author states that in `printf()`, %o and %x, denote **unsigned** octal integers and **unsigned** hexadecimal integers respectively, but in `scanf()`, %o and %x, interpret **signed** octal integers and **signed** hexadecimal integers respectively. Why is it so?

I wrote the following program in VS 2015 to check the author's statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
{
   int a, b, c;

   printf("Enter number: ");
   scanf("%x %x", &a, &b);
   c = a + b;
   printf("Answer = %x\n", c);


   while (getchar() != EOF)
      getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

The code proved the author's claim.

If the inputs had a pair integers where the absolute value of the positive integer was **bigger** than the absolute value of the negative integer, then everything worked fine.

But if the inputs had a pair integers where the absolute value of the positive integer was **smaller** than the absolute value of the negative integer, then the output was what you would expect from **unsigned** 2's complement.

For example:

```
Enter number: -5 6
Answer = 1
```

and

```
Enter number: -6 5
Answer = ffffffff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard says that for printf-like functions (7.21.6.1 fprintf):

> o,u,x,X
>   The **unsigned int** argument is converted to unsigned octal
>   (o), unsigned decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (x or X)

While for scanf-like functions it says (7.21.6.2 fscanf):

> x
>   Matches an optionally signed hexadecimal integer, whose format is the same
>   as expected for the subject sequence of the strtoul function with the value
>   16 for the base argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   unsigned integer.

So as an extra feature, you can write a negative hex number and scanf will convert it to the corresponding unsigned number in the system's format (two's complement).

For example

```
unsigned int x;
scanf("%x", &x); // enter -1
printf("%x", x); // will print ffffffff
```

Why they felt like scanf needed this mildly useful feature, I have no idea. Perhaps it is there for consistency with other conversion specifiers.

However, the book seems to be using the function incorrectly, since the standard explicitly states that you must pass a pointer to unsigned int. If you pass a pointer to a signed int, you are formally invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Doesn't it bother you how hard it is to format this kind of text?

Comment: @iharob Yep, SO quotes are pretty user-unfriendly :) One secret trick is to add two spaces after a row inside a quote to get a new line.

Comment: No, I know that but I wanted it to look exactly as it does in the PDF. See my answer, it's the only solution I found.

Comment: @iharob `<pre>` html tags seem to do the trick, but then you won't get the fancy yellow background.

Comment: @Lundin: I typically use the `<blockquote>` tags, then use other HTML tags such as `<strong>`, `<em>`, `<pre>` and `<code>` within the blockquote as necessary.  PITA, but it works.

Comment: @Olaf As it says, it is processed just like a call to strtoul. Likely, scanf() calls that function internally on most implementations.

Comment: @Lundin: Sorry, not my day. I thought strtoul does not intepret the minus sign. just forget it:-)

Answer (score 1):

Reading the C11 specification, section 7.21.6.2/12, it says for the `o` format:

> Matches an optionally signed octal integer, whose format is the same as
>   expected for the subject sequence of the `strtoul` function with the value 8
>   for the `base` argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   unsigned integer.

<sub>With corresponding text for the hexadecimal `x` format.</sub>

So on one hand the specification says the input *can* be signed, but it also says the format is the same as for the [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) function which reads *unsigned* integers, and the result is stored in an *unsigned* integer.

Comment: I saw from my sample program that `scanf()` can indeed take in signed values for octal and hexadecimal integers. Would you please run my program in your system and use inputs like I did?

Comment: @ShabbirKhan: Point is, you have to use `unsigned int` arguments (pointers for `scanf`), not signed `int`. Accepting a preceeding minus sign is indeed a bit ... unexpected.

Comment: @Olaf, thanks for the information! I will keep it mind.

Comment: "`strtoul` function which reads unsigned integers" is incomplete.  `strtoul()` reads _unsigned_ **and** _signed_ textual representations of numbers.  The result is `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the author is wrong as @[Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33216530/1983495) pointed out

This is what the standard says about it

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**<sup>1</sup>
>
> 12 The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> o        Matches an **optionally** signed octal integer, whose format is the same as
>        
>          expected for the subject sequence of the strtoul function with the value 8
>        
>          for the base argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>        
>          unsigned integer.
>
> x          Matches an **optionally** signed hexadecimal integer, whose format is the
>          same as expected for the subject sequence of the strtoul function with 
>          the value 16 for the base argument. The corresponding argument 
>          shall be 
>        a pointer to unsigned integer.

as you can read above it's **optionally** signed but it certainly expects a pointer to and *unsigned* integer

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Of course I have omitted a lot, in fact `fscanf()` is one of the largest sections in the standard document.</sub>