# Why my program is skipping the digit 8 and 9?

Tags: c, cs50

I need some help.
I designed the program to give me the first digit and then skip the next digit, and so on. But every time it comes to the digit 8, the result is 10 instead of 8, so with the digit 9, it will be 11. This does not happen with any digit other than 8 and 9.
After many attempts, I noticed that the same thing is repeated when sum1 reaches 17. If you add 1 or another number, it will skip 18 and 19, and takes the value 20.
It seems to me as if the program is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 20 21 22.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int count = 8 ;
  long number = 12345678 ;
  long the_remainder ;
  long sum1 = 0 ;

  for (int i = 0 ; i < (count / 2) ; i++)
  {
     the_remainder = number % 10 ;
    
     printf(" the_remainder is %lo\n", the_remainder);
    
     number = number / 100 ;
    
     sum1 = sum1 + the_remainder ;
    
     printf("the sum is : %lo\n", sum1);
  }
}
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKx7Z.jpg)

Comment: duplicates: [What does the format specifiers “%02x ” and “%3o ” do in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58262817/995714), [Why do the conversion specifiers, %o and %x, work differently for printf() and scanf() in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33216448/995714), [What is the following format specifier doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66020521/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `%d` instead of `%o`. Because `%o` will print octal integers and your expected answer is of base 10 (decimal).

Answer (score 1):

The `%o` format specifier outputs in octal format, which is why the value 8 appears as `10`.

You want to use `%ld` instead, which print in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the format specifier `%o` which will print out *octal* (i.e. base-8) integers. There is obviously no digit `8` or `9` in base-8.

Use `%d` or `%ld` for base 10.